# Why is the search not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have an array and I am trying to do a real time search. So originally I will have the unfiltered array and as I search the table view will update as I type. I have set the delegate, so I am lost on why it is not working. Any help is appreciated :)

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var searchController = UISearchController()
var unfilitered = ["cat", "dog", "bat", "tiger"]
var filtered = [String]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureSearchController()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: searchcell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as! searchcell

    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        cell.animal.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.animal.text = unfiltered[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        return filtered.count
    }
    else {
        return unfiltered.count
    }
}

func configureSearchController() {
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    table.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = true
    table.reloadData()
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = false
    table.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if !shouldShowSearchResults {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        table.reloadData()
    }

    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text


    filtered = unfiltered.filter({ (animal) -> Bool in
        let animalText: NSString = animal

        return (animalText.rangeOfString(searchString!, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
    })

    table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `filtered` contains what you want? Is `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` being called?

Comment: I just added a couple of breakpoints and checked, and the DidBeginEditing is not being called.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set the delegate for the `UITextField`. You could just set `shouldShowSearchResults` in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`.

Comment: I do though it's the first line in the `configureSearchController` which is called in the viewDidLoad

Comment: You should be able to use 'searchController.active` instead of a separate boolean

Comment: What does the active method do exactly?

Comment: `active` tells you whether or not the search bar is showing. However, I just notice you're resetting `searchController` to a new instance on the fourth line of `configureSearchController`. You should delete that line.

Comment: You used searhcell when I think you meant searchcell.

Answer (score 0):

The reloadData method won't force a redraw of the tableView unless it's performed on the main thread.

Comment: So in the `upadteSearchResultsForSearchController` run the table.reloadData on the main thread?

Comment: Yes.  `[table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)]` in Objective-C.  (Not confident enough in my Swift skill to write it out in Swift, sorry.)